# How can I find out who and when deleted particular database user from oracle database

Tags: oracle

I am trying to investigate some database users that used to exist in the system. I am interested when and who deleted the database user from the oracle database. Does oracle have any table or way to track deleted users?

Comment: we provide a complete audit trail...assuming it's enabled

Answer (score 1):

You can check the DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL or UNIFIED_AUDIT_TRAIL views for records, but if you didn't already have it enabled the audit trail won't have captured what happened and there's no way to find out.

Going forward, if you need to enable it here's a couple of posts on auditing and basic configurations. The first, from my blog, has a quick script for basic audits including account creation and deletion using Unified Auditing:

- https://pmdba.wordpress.com/2020/03/10/auditing-by-the-numbers/
- https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dbseg/introduction-to-auditing.html#GUID-94381464-53A3-421B-8F13-BD171C867405
- https://oracle-base.com/articles/8i/auditing

The first thing to do is enable full Unified Auditing. This introduces several built-in access controls and tools that will make auditing of the database simpler. To enable Unified Auditing, complete the following steps:

1. Confirm whether or not UA is already enabled. If the response to the
   following query is "TRUE", then it is.

   SELECT * FROM V$OPTION WHERE
       PARAMETER = 'Unified Auditing';
2. If UA is *not* enabled, then follow the steps in [Section
   4.6.13.2](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/UPGRD/afterup.htm#CHDFBBAG) of the Oracle Database Upgrade Guide to turn it on.
3. Enable basic audit policies:

   -- audit granting and revocation of any privilege:

   create audit policy stig_grant_privilege_actions actions grant, revoke;

   -- audit all OLS administrative actions:

   create audit policy stig_ols_admin_actions actions component = OLS all;

   -- audit all user logon and logoff attempts:

   create audit policy stig_user_logon_actions actions logon, logoff;

   -- audit execution of any PL/SQL program unit:

   create audit policy stig_execute_plsql_actions actions execute;

   -- audit all user administration actions:

   create audit policy stig_user_admin_actions actions create user, alter user, drop user, change password;

   -- audit any database parameter changes, dynamic or static:

   create audit policy stig_db_param_actions actions alter database, alter system, create spfile;

   -- apply policies:

   audit policy stig_grant_privilege_actions;

   audit policy stig_ols_admin_actions;

   audit policy stig_user_logon_actions;

   audit policy stig_execute_plsql_actions;

   audit policy stig_user_admin_actions;

   audit policy stig_db_param_actions;

Comment: If you are linking to your own website then you should [edit] your post to include [disclosure of this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299621/is-it-enough-disclosure-of-self-promotion-if-the-link-itself-contains-their-name). Or better, post the relevant detail from the links into your answer so that it becomes a self-contained solution and not something hidden behind multiple links.